# Make an optional Get variable with this htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^build_system/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /po_systems/build_system.php?business_id=$1&system_id=$2&quantity=$3
```

Which works great for this url:

```
http://somesite.com/po_systems/build_system/60/495C31/1
```

But now I need an optional 4th `Get` variable to this rule that will give me the `$_GET` variable step like this:

```
http://somesite.com/po_systems/build_system/60/495C31/1/2

$_GET['step'] // 2
```

But I also need the rule to work if there is no 4th `Get` variable. So basically I need both 3 and 4 `Get` variables to work, making the 4th optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it with two separate rules:

```
RewriteRule ^build_system/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /po_systems/build_system.php?business_id=$1&system_id=$2&quantity=$3&step=$4 [S=1]
RewriteRule ^build_system/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$         /po_systems/build_system.php?business_id=$1&system_id=$2&quantity=$3
```

If there are 4 path components, the first rule will match, and skip the next rule (`[S=1]`).  Otherwise the next rule will try to match.

@Ulrich Palha's solution probably also works, but the regular expression is getting complicated.  It will pass an empty `step=` parameter if there's no 4th path component, which may be fine.  My solution will pass no `step` parameter if there's no 4th path component.  Either way should work.

Comment: It means "skip the next rule if this one matches".  See the [RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
RewriteRule ^build_system/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?$ /po_systems/build_system.php?business_id=$1&system_id=$2&quantity=$3&step=$4
```